# OVA to QCOW2 conversion - Openstack instance dracut initqueue timeout and could not boot

Tags: centos, openstack, qcow2

I have a custom OVA built with Centos 7 and trying to convert it to qcow2.

I have extracted the files from the OVA and converted the vmdk to qcow2 with following command:

`qemu-img convert -O qcow2 image.vmdk image.qcow2`

After uploading the qcow2 image and creating the instance in openstack I am stuck with the following message after boot(shared screenshot)

[image: Boot erro message]

I am missing something while creating qcow2, any suggestion on this issue.

Comment: Does the original vmdk image contain all that information about the logical volumes? In other words, is it complete? I haven't dealt with vmdk yet, but you can debug the image in rescue mode (`openstack server rescue <UUID>` or `nova rescue --image <IMAGE> <UUID>`) to try to find the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Run "dracut -fMa qemu" on the source CentOS.
Replicate and re-run the migration and the issue should be resolved.